# Rook polynomials with several sets of rooks?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

Is there some article or other reference where the notion of
several sets of rook placements on Ferrers boards is considered?
That is, one might have, say black rooks and white rooks, and each set considered individually should be non-attacking.

Comment: Have you checked https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04238, it seems that has a short introduction and reference therein.